# Problem extracting a table from basketball-reference using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I want to extract a specific table having id = "all_team-stats-per_game". I'm trying to extract the column headers. I'm able to correctly find the table with the specific id but not sure why the output is null when I search for the tag "tr". The code is attached below. Thanks in advance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# NBA season we will be analyzing
year = 2019

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html"

# this is the HTML from the given URL
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# use findALL() to get the column headers
# soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)

soup = soup.find(id="all_team-stats-per_game")

print(soup.find_all('th'))
#
# headers = [th.getText() for th in soup[0].findAll('th')]
#
# print(headers)
```

Comment: Because there is no `th` tag at all. You omitted it.  in this line `soup = soup.find_all('tr')`

Comment: @Tserenjamts Thank You. I'm new to data extraction. Can you please let me know how I can keep the th header?

Comment: You got `th` already `soup = soup.find(id="all_team-stats-per_game")` this gave you full table that means `th` is included.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I updated my code. But the search for th header is still returning NULL.

Comment: That table you wanted to get is not `table` but `div`.

Comment: And before crawling data you should check structure of things that you want to get. :))) there is no `th` but `thead`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to edit your code. I am able to find the required div tag but the table inside is mentioned as a comment and i verified it using the inspect tool also. So maybe that is why it is not picking up the table content

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# NBA season we will be analyzing
year = 2019

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019.html"

# this is the HTML from the given URL
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

# use findALL() to get the column headers
# soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)

target_div = soup.find("div", {"id": "all_team-stats-per_game"})

print(target_div.prettify())
#
# headers = [th.getText() for th in soup[0].findAll('th')]
#
# print(headers)
```

Comment: I figured this is the problem. Now I'm trying to remove the comment tags without deleting the contents i.e. preserving the table itself. Can you tell me how to do it because I'm only able to find a solution that can remove comments alongwith its contents. Thank You